# How do I override DrawItem for BS_SPLITBUTTON buttons

Tags: c++, mfc

If I make a new button class inheriting from `CButton`, specifying the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style , and overriding the `DrawItem` method I can control the rendering of the button, like this:

```
void CMyButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct) {
    CDC dc;
    dc.Attach(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    RECT rect = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem;
    dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(0, 0xFF, 0));
    dc.Detach();
}

m_button.Create(L"Foo", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_OWNERDRAW, CRect(0, 150, 100, 200), this, IDC_FOO);
```

I get the following result:

[image]

which is what I hoped for. However if I instead inherit my button from CSplitButton, which adds the `BS_SPLITBUTTON` style, I get the following result:

[image]

which is *not* the result I had hoped for (I had hoped it would look exactly the same as the `CButton`). The `DrawItem` method isn't being called in this case so I guess `BS_SPLITBUTTONS` are treated differently by the system.

How can I get the result I want, a button with split button behaviour with customized drawing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it [says in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for **BS_OWNERDRAW**:

> Creates an owner-drawn button. The owner window receives a WM_DRAWITEM
>   message when a visual aspect of the button has changed. **Do not
>   combine the BS_OWNERDRAW style with any other button styles**.

(My emphasis).

If you're doing your own drawing, you have to do *all* of it yourself.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I'll post a new question on how to emulate a split button then.