# How can I emulate the BS_SPLITBUTTON functionality

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to implement a split button with custom rendering:

[How do I override DrawItem for BS_SPLITBUTTON buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547426/how-do-i-override-drawitem-for-bs-splitbutton-buttons)

Apparently if I use `BS_OWNERDRAW` I can't use the `BS_SPLITBUTTON` style as well. What would be the easiest way of emulating the split button functionality while also making custom rendering possible?

Comment: `CMFCMenuButton` is quite similar to `CSplitButton` and doesn't use owner-drawn style. Perhaps you can derive from this and override `OnDraw`? (Just a theory after a quick peek at the code) ...

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the source code of CMFCMenuButton and implemented a version of my own